# Having trouble with my analysis. I have no one to ask. I thought I would post here

Tags: biostatistics, kruskal-wallis-test, methodology, genetics, dunn-test

I performed an experiment where I shocked fish eggs at different times prior to first cellular cleavage, this was to create tetraploid fish larvae.

I have a control group and then 9 treatments (60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, and 100% of the cellular cleavage). All treatment groups were conducted in triplicate, a total of 30 experimental units.

To analyze, I collected ploidy from ten larvae in each experimental unit. Then I created a table with two columns, "treatment" and "tetraploid." The "tetraploid" column was populated with the percent of tetraploids sampled from each experimental unit. I then checked for normality and homogeneity of variances, the data was not normal, and variances were not homogenous. I arcsine transformed the percent data and still it was not normal, and variances were not homogenous. I then ran a Kruskal.test, and found that the P-value was 0.012. However, when I ran a Dunn's post hoc test (bonferroni method) none of the treatment groups were significantly different from each other.

What makes me most confused is that I have one treatment group that is 100% tetraploid. Why isnt this group statistically different from the controls (controls are 0% tetraploid)??

I have never asked a question on these forums, but I reference them all the time, because R and statistics are very challenging for me. I have seen that this "significant Kruskal, insignificant Dunn's" is a thing that happens. I guess I just want some help determining if there is a better was to analyze this data. Or for someone to help me interpret the results that I am getting from the Kruskal/Dunn's.

Comment: Please change the title of your question to something that meaningfully describes the substance of your question.

Comment: What is the power of your test given the sample? To put it in other way, given the size of your populations, what is the smallest level of difference between groups you can expect to detect (e.g. with probability of 80%+)?

Comment: How does it compare to the size of the effect that would be expected based on theory? e.g. if theoretically expected difference is 1 but you are only powered up to detect difference of 10 or more, then, perhaps you should not be surprised to see no difference between groups

Comment: Do you have the original data used to calculate %? At least the n`s?

Comment: As your outcome data are the fractions of eggs that became tetraploid, you should be using a method like logistic regression that is designed for such data. I suspect that if you do that many of your problems will go away, particularly if you model the "times prior to first cellular cleavage" as a continuous predictor (maybe with a regression spline) instead of setting up a separate category for each time.